# Program C count words (excluding numbers)

Tags: c, string, loops, if-statement, counting

I have come across a lot of counting words examples (like the one in the link below):

[Counting words in a string - c programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698836/counting-words-in-a-string-c-programming)

```
if(str[i]==' ')
{
    i++;
}
```

and for digit is:

```
if(str[i]>='0' && str[i]<='9')
{
    i++;
}
```

but what if the input were 'I have 12 apples.' and I only want the output to show "word count = 3"?

Comment: You'll need to [tokenise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266357/tokenizing-strings-in-c) the input, then count how many tokens are "words" (or at least, consist of entirely alphabetical characters, or whatever else your classification strategy is).

Comment: You could have a look at `strtok`

Comment: What if the word starts with a number, like `123hello`, or contains a number (`he123llo`), should it be counted then or not?

Comment: Then you need to think about it. And BTW, neither of the two conditions above is good for what they claim to do. Consider double spaces and what not.

Comment: You dont need to explicity tokenise the input.  A char-by-char state-machine would also be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you don't have words that contain alphanumeric combinations, like "foo12", then you could combine your code snippets, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "Bex 67 rep";
    int len = strlen(str);
    int count = 0, i = 0;
    while(str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(str[i] == ' ')
        {
            if(i + 1 < len && ! (str[i + 1] >= '0' && str[i + 1] <= '9') && str[i + 1] != ' ')
                count++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("Word count = %d\n", count + 1); // Word count = 2
    return 0;
}
```

where you loop over every character of the string, and when you find a whitespace, you check - if you are not at the last character of the string - if the next character is *not* a digit or a whitespace. If that's the case, then you can assume that the whitespace you encountered is precedended of a word, thus incease `count`.

Notice however that usually senteces do not start with a whitespace (which is an extra assumption for this answer), thus the number of words is one more than `count`.

---

In real life, use [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) and check every token for its validity, since that's approach is just for demonstration and should be considered a *bad approach*.

Comment: `str[i] == ' '` is a bad approach for counting words. For example, `" test"` would return a wrong result.

Comment: I agree @Groo, answer updated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char str[] ="I have 12 apples";
    char * pch;
    unsigned long ul;
    int cnt=0;

    pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        ul = strtoul (pch, NULL, 0);
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
        printf("%d\n", ul);
        if(ul == 0)
            cnt++;
    }
    printf("count is %d\n", cnt);
    return 0;
}
```

String tokens parsed using strtok function.

Answer (score 0):

My five cents.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

size_t count_words( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    const char *p = s;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        int pos = 0;

        sscanf( p, "%*[ \t]%n", &pos );
        p += pos;

        if ( sscanf( p, "%*s%n", &pos ) == EOF ) break;

        if ( isalpha( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++n;

        p += pos;
    }


    return n;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "I have 12 apples";

    printf( "The number of words is %zu\n", count_words( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The number of words is 3
```

And my advice is do not use the standard function `strtok` for such a task. First of all it may not deal with string literals. And it has a side effect of changing the original string.:)